# Clang++ non-static data member initialization error? C++11

Tags: c++, c++11, clang, libc++, member-initialization

I can't seem to figure out what Clang is saying or whether it's right as G++-4.7 seems to compile it fine.

The error comes from trying to initialize `std::uniform_int_distribution` with curly braces for a non-static member.

The following fails (`token_count` is a template parameter):
`std::uniform_int_distribution<Int> random_dist{0, token_count-1};`

with the error:

```
error: chosen constructor is explicit in copy-initialization
  std::uniform_int_distribution<Int> random_dist{0, b-1};
                                                ^~~~~~~~

/usr/include/c++/v1/algorithm:2644:14: note: constructor declared here
    explicit uniform_int_distribution(result_type __a = 0,
```

I can, however, initialize it by doing this:

`std::uniform_int_distribution<Int> random_dist = std::uniform_int_distribution<Int>(0, token_count - 1);`

I am using the following command to compile it: `clang++ -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ -lc++abi` with Clang-3.2.

Output of `clang -v`:

```
clang version 3.2 (trunk 157320)
Target: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
```

Comment: Can you give us the exact output from `clang -v`?

Comment: Perhaps you could use the old-school `std::uniform_int_distribution<Int> random_dist(0, token_count-1)`.

Comment: This [bug](http://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=12120) *may* be the relevant one, but I'm not sure.

Comment: When it comes to non-static data member initialization, only `=` or `{}` may be used to initialize.

Comment: What is `Int` and `token_count`? Apart from that it works for me -- clang version 3.2 (trunk 157115).

Comment: Int is just an alias for the smallest integer capable of holding a template parameter called token_count. I updated to clang 3.2 (trunk 157522). Are you using libc++?

Answer (score 1):

You probably have a version of clang that does not yet implement generalized initializers.  Tip-of-trunk clang compiles your code.  You can check for this feature with:

```
#if __has_feature(cxx_generalized_initializers)
```

Here's the list of features you can check for:

http://clang.llvm.org/docs/LanguageExtensions.html#cxx11

Comment: Well, he does say that he used Clang 3.2, which I would find a bit strange to not support generalized initializers, since those were already working in Clang 3.1. I can, however, confirm that Clang 3.2 r156775 definitely compiles the code.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it was a recent bug fix.

Comment: Perhaps we also need: __has_feature(cxx_nonstatic_member_init)

Comment: Just tested `cxx_generalized_initializers` and `cxx_nonstatic_member_init`, and both work.